# Flux/Redux trigger a side-effect at the end of an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux, react-redux

I can't understand how to make such a pattern work in Flux/Redux:

- A component `Input` triggers an action when data is entered;
- A component `Draw` listens to the `store` to get some long strings;
- Based on these strings, it computes a *lot* of points that it plots in a canvas (in `this.componentDidUpdate`). To not save all the points in memory (suppose their number is really too big), it draws them one by one in a loop;
- During the process, it saves a reduced form of the data (a distribution of the points);
- At the end, I would like to make another component update using the reduced data.

But I cannot trigger an action at the end, because it would trigger re-rendering infinitely. Is there some recommended way to do this?

The best I could imagine was to draw on the canvas in my reducer/action, and update only the state of the second component as the result of the action. But then if it is re-rendered somehow otherwise, the canvas will be empty.

In flux I would use a `setTimeout(, 0)` hack and two different stores, but it does not work with Redux as all listen to the same store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing lots of async stuff there's plenty of redux async libraries and [well documented approaches](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html). However if this is the only part of your app that needs to wait for something else to finish I might suggest having a status like `DATA_PROCESSING_STATUS` in the store. When you first get the new data, you set this to "processing", when it's finished, you dispatch another event to set the status to "done".

Then in your second component, react to the change.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const wasProcessing = this.props.DATA_PROCESSING_STATUS === 'PROCESSING';
    const isNowNotProcessing = newProps.DATA_PROCESSING_STATUS !== 'PROCESSING';
    if (wasProcessing && isNowNotProcessing) {
      // new data is ready, use it in some way
    }
  }
```

IMO it's a fairly fiddly approach, but if this is the only instance of wanting to do something async, then the fiddlyness is contained here. Implementing a full-on async flux flow might be overkill in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I think that link has everything to solve my problem. I did not realize I was describing an async problem. I'll validate the answer once I manage to make that work.